# Show constant URL for site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site with number of pages, developing in asp.net.
    I have a page URL's like:
    example:

```
1) http://www.xyz.com/Home.aspx 
2) http://www.xyz.com/Index.aspx
3) http://www.xyz.com/viewMember?Name=abc&id=1
```

But the end user is at any page, i would like to show the URL like `"http://www.xyz.ie"`.

Is there any setting in web.config ? If not, is there any other way ?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance.
Jagadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not keep one single URL for different page - but you can do some tricks to simulate it.

To make the url stay the same, but the content change, you need to make some trick.

I am not recommend, search engines they will not follow what you do and they show each page different, user can not make bookmark, and average user can easy find the real url of the page, even with one different click on the browser can find it.

One trick is to use frames, or iframes. On the main page you load all the rest inside an iframe, or inside a frame.

Second trick is to use ajax to load each other content.

And finally you can use session to know what to show on the user, user did not change links, but make post back that change the content.